# How to pass mail data from service provider to config/mail.php in laravel 4

Tags: database, laravel, email, laravel-4, phpmailer

I was fetch mail configuration data using model file, and pass it to my provider the name CofigServiceProvider.php. But i don't know how to pass it into config/mail.php file. Because i need to change the mail configuration data dynamically from my admin panel. or Any other way to fetch db values and pass it app/config/mail.php in laravel 4

ConfigServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Config;
use Home;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
public function register() {
$smtpdata = Home::get_smtp_data();
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $smtpdata->sm_host);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.port', $smtpdata->sm_port);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $smtpdata->sm_uname);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $smtpdata->sm_pwd);
}
}
```

Home.php(model)

```
public static function get_smtp_data()
{
    return DB::table('nm_smtp')->where('sm_isactive','=', 1)->first();
}
```

**config/Mail.php:**

```
<?php
return array(
'driver' => 'smtp',

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 

'port' => 465, 
 /*
'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
===> */
'from' => array('address' => 'myaccount@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Laravel'),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'myname@gmail.com',
'password' => '******',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,

 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus update your ConfigServiceProvider like,

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Config;
use Home;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
public function register() {
$smtpdata = Home::get_smtp_data();
Config::set('mail.host', $smtpdata->sm_host);
Config::set('mail.port', $smtpdata->sm_port);
Config::set('mail.username', $smtpdata->sm_uname);
Config::set('mail.password', $smtpdata->sm_pwd);
}
}
```