# Laravel Mailable classes not including "name" in address

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Since I migrated the old fashioned way of sending emails to the Mailable classes, two situations came up (barely problems) but they are annoying me.

**1)** I'm using the global "from" configuration set in the config/mail.php file to avoid setting it in each mailable class I write:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => 'ble@somemail.org',
    'name' => 'My sender name',
]
```

The emails are being sent from the right "From" address, but the "name" is not being included.

**2)** I'm also using the awesome new functionality of sending as parameter in the recipients function `->to(XX)`, the entire User instance or collection of Users. It works almost perfect, just one more situation: The recipient is also not including the "name" attribute of the User instance for each sender.

Pretty similar both of them right? Is there some config left that I may be missing?

I'm using Laravel 5.3

Thanks a lot,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804768/how-to-pass-mail-data-from-service-provider-to-config-mail-php-in-laravel-4

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with the original question, moreover it is based on laravel 4. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was having a similar problem to your 2nd issue, albeit in 5.5. Only way I could get it to work was to make a simple custom class `RecipientUser` with two global properties "name" and "email":

`$recipient = new RecipientUser($recipient_name, $recipient_email);`
`$result = Mail::to($recipient)->send($mailable);`

Maybe these weird bits will be less weird in 5.6 or 5.7.